# java version not found in redhat

Tags: linux, bash, rhel, java, alternatives

My OS is redhat linux. It's having the default java 1.4.2, but I need java 1.7.45,
for that I am trying as follows:

```
/usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /u01/java7/bin/java 5
/usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /u01/java7/bin/java 2

/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.4.2-gcj/bin/java
 + 2           /u01/java7/bin/java
```

Here i am selecting 2nd one

After that i am getting the message

```
[root@localhost bin]# java --version
bash: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
```

so please give me solution for resolving this problem in redhat linux

```
[root@localhost bin]# java --version
bash: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file
```

Comment: Can you execute `/u01/java7/bin/java` or does that give the same error?

Comment: Could have been a binary for different architecture...